# Calling flet or labels functions in clisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I new to common lisp (clisp-2.49)

Can I call an `flet` or `labels` function from a different outside function?
If so, how? (In a source file)

This code works except for the last print statement where it loses scope to `f(n)` on the last line.

```
(labels ((f (n)
         (+ n 10)))
  (print(f 5)))

(print (f 2))
```

Comment: Functions defined with `FLET`/`LABELS` are only visible in the lexical scope, although you can pass them outside it as values which can be called with `FUNCALL`/`APPLY` (eg. `(funcall (flet ((f () :foo)) #'f))`).

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

Functions and macros created by
[`flet`/`labels`/`macrolet`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_flet_.htm) are
***local***, i.e., they exist only inside the form, just like variables
bound by [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) are local.

If you need to refer to them outside of a function, you need to use
[`defun`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm)/[`defmacro`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defmac.htm).

On the other hand, you can have many forms inside a `flet`:

```
(flet ((logger (format-string &rest args)
         (apply #'format t format-string args)
         (fresh-line)))
  (defun f1 (x)
    (logger "Called f1 on ~S" x)
    (- x))
  (defun f2 (x)
    (logger "Called f2 on ~S" x)
    (1+ x)))
> (f1 10)
Called f1 on 10
==> -10
> (f2 4)
Called f2 on 4
==> 5
> (f1 (f2 (f1 5)))
Called f1 on 5
Called f2 on -5
Called f1 on -4
==> 4
```

You can only use `logger` inside `flet` body (IOW, in `f1` and `f2`), but not outside the `flet`.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I call an flet or labels function from a different outside function?

Yes! As others have mentioned, the lexical scope of the `flet`
definition is local.  But the *extent* of the value is infinite.  I.e. as long as 'something' within the Lisp system is pointing to it, its value will be preserved indefinitely.

But you might ask, how can that be done if lexical scoping denies you the name of the `flet` outside of the function?  The following will illustrate:

```
(defun my-closure ()
  (let ((i 5))
    (flet ((my-flet ()
         (setf i (+ i 1))))
      #'my-flet)))

;; Assign the returned value (a closure) to the 'global' special
;; variable global-my-closure
(defparameter global-my-closure (my-closure))

;; Call it *without* using the #' style prefix that you would use for
;; globally bound functions.  This is a special variable whose value
;; happens to be that of a function.
(funcall global-my-closure)
6
(funcall global-my-closure)
7
(funcall global-my-closure)
8
```

Note, this is an extrodinarily powerful concept.  One of the best programming books of all time, The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, explores this topic in detail using the related Lisp languange, Scheme, which has a slightly more convenient syntax for manipulating closures.

Answer (score 0):

Related to the answer by Earl D, you can do things like this

```
(defmacro define-function (name v)
  `(progn
     (setf (fdefinition ',name) ,v)
     ',name))
```

Then

```
(define-function global-x (let ((s 0))
                            (labels ((local-x (a)
                                       (incf s a)))
                              #'local-x)))
```

Will do what you think it should.

This is slightly more different than the `(let ... (defun ...))` case than it seems: in that case, the defining macro (`defun` here) is not at top-level, even if the `let` is, and that can result in various hair when compiling things.